# Apex SelectList value not pulling into controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here. I've done this before multiple times without a problem but for some reason it's not working here. On my VF componentI have the following:

```
                            <apex:repeat value="{!newAttachments}"
                                         var="newAtt">
                                <apex:selectList value="{!newAtt.Description}" size="1"
                                    multiselect="false" styleClass="bold" id="docsList">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}" />
                                </apex:selectList>
                                <br/>
                            </apex:repeat>`
```

In my controller I have:

```
for(Integer i=0;i<newAttachments.size();i++){
        system.debug('DESC: '+newAttachments[i].Description );}
```

in an action method called from a submit button. The value is always null and I don't know why.

The selectListOptions are populated with the following:

```
for (Standard_Document__c obj : docs){
             options.add(new selectOption(obj.Document_Name__c, obj.Document_Name__c));
        }
```

And I know that has a value since the picklist shows correctly on the page.

Full component:

```
<apex:component controller="OIPHPRMTrimCtrl" allowDML="true">
<apex:attribute name="objId" type="String"
    description="The id of the object to manage attachments for"
    required="true" assignTo="{!sobjId}" />
<apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" />
<apex:pageMessages />

<style>
    select {
        margin: 2px;
    }
</style>
<apex:form id="attForm">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Upload Documents">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Project Details">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="2" border="1px" cellpadding="10">
                <tr>
                    <th>Project Name:<apex:outputLink value="{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}{!oId}"> {!oppName}</apex:outputLink></th>
                    <th>Project Id: <apex:outputLink value="{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}{!oId}"> {!oppId}</apex:outputLink></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock id="uploadType" title="Upload Type">
            <apex:selectRadio id="uploadOptions" value="{!selectionType}"
                onchange="switchDropdown(this);">
                <apex:selectOption id="uploadDocType" itemValue="DocumentType"
                    itemLabel="Document Name (Standard)" />
                <apex:selectOption id="uploadTRIMFolder" itemValue="TRIMFolder"
                    itemLabel="Document Name (Other)" />
            </apex:selectRadio>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock id="docsBlock" title="Document Information">

            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0px" cellpadding="10">
                <tr>
                    <td class="labelCol" width="15%">
                        <apex:outputLabel id="disciplineSectionItemSub" value="Discipline" >
                            <span style="color: red; vertical-align: bottom">*</span>
                        </apex:outputLabel>                     
                    </td>
                    <td width="30%">                            
                        <apex:actionRegion>
                            <apex:selectList value="{!Discipline.id}" size="1"
                                multiselect="false" styleClass="bold" id="disciplineList"
                                onchange="updatePicklist();">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Disciplines}" />
                            </apex:selectList>
                            <apex:actionFunction name="updatePicklist" action="{!SetDocumentType}" rerender="TRIMDocs, docsList"/>
                        </apex:actionRegion>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%"/>
                    <td width="40%"/>
                </tr>
                <apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:outputPanel id="docInfoSection">  
                    <tr>
                        <td id="docsSectionItemA1" class="labelCol">
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Document Type" />                          
                        </td>
                        <td id="docsSectionItemA2" >
                            <apex:repeat value="{!newAttachments}"
                                         var="newAtt">
                                <apex:selectList value="{!newAtt.Description}" size="1"
                                    multiselect="false" styleClass="bold" id="docsList">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Description}" />
                                </apex:selectList>
                                <br/>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </td>                           
                        <td id="docsSectionItemTRIMA1" class="labelCol">
                                <apex:outputLabel value="HPRM Folder" />                    
                        </td>
                        <td id="docsSectionItemTRIMA2" >
                            <apex:repeat value="{!newAttachmentsTRIM}" var="newAtt">
                                <apex:selectList value="{!newAtt.Description}" size="1"
                                                 multiselect="false" styleClass="bold" id="TRIMDocs">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!TRIMDescription}" />
                                </apex:selectList>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </td>   
                    </tr>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                    <tr>                                        
                        <td class="labelCol" >  
                            <div align="right">                 
                                <apex:selectRadio id="fileOpt" value="{!fileType}"
                                    onchange="switchFile(this);">
                                    <apex:selectOption id="fileType" itemValue="File"
                                        itemLabel="File" />
                                    <apex:selectOption id="folderType" itemValue="Folder"
                                        itemLabel="Folder" />
                                </apex:selectRadio>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputPanel id="fileInput">
                                <apex:repeat value="{!newAttachments}" var="newAtt">
                                    <apex:inputFile styleClass="inputFile" value="{!newAtt.body}"
                                                    filename="{!newAtt.name}" />
                                    <br/>                               
                                </apex:repeat>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                                <apex:repeat value="{!newAttachments}" var="newAtt">                                        
                                    <apex:inputTextArea rows="1" id="folderInput" style="width: 300px" value="{!newAtt.description}"/>
                                    <br/>                               
                                </apex:repeat>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:actionRegion>
                <tr>
                    <td class="labelCol">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Document Description" />   
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <apex:inputField style="width:320px;" value="{!document.Description__c}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="labelCol">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Document Date" />  
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!document.Document_Date__c}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Add Multiple" action="{!addMore}" />
                <input class="btn" type="button"
                    onclick="validate(); return false;" value="Upload Document(s)" />
                <apex:actionFunction name="callUpload" action="{!upload}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<apex:form rendered="{!documents.size>0}" id="thisForm">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Existing Document Links" id="existingDocuments">
        <Apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!documents}" var="document" id="docList">
            <apex:column width="150px" value="{!document.Document_Name__c}" />
            <apex:column width="150px" value="{!document.TRIM_Document_Type__c}" />
            <apex:column width="150px" value="{!document.Folder_Location__c}" />
            <apex:column width="150px" value="{!document.TRIM_Link__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

<script
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="//malsup.github.io/min/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var upload = true;
        var fileSelected = false;

        $('.inputFile').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                if ($(this).parent().next().find('.bold').val() == '' 
                    && $(this).parent().next().next().find('.bold').val() == '') {
                    upload = false;
                }
               fileSelected = true;
            }
        });
        if (upload && fileSelected){
          callUpload();
        } else if (!fileSelected) {
          alert('No Documents to upload.  Select the documents to upload before clicking on Upload button');
        } else
        alert('Please select descriptions for all documents.');
    }

    j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); 

    j$(document).ready(function(){
        setVisibility();
    });

    function setVisibility(){
        var dtype = '{!selectionType}';
        var ftype = '{!fileType}';

        if(ftype === 'File'){
            j$('[id*=fileInput]').show();
            j$('[id*=folderInput]').hide();
        }else{
            j$('[id*=fileInput]').hide();
            j$('[id*=folderInput]').show();
        }
        if(dtype === 'DocumentType'){
            j$('[id*=docsSectionItemA]').show();
            j$('[id*=docsSectionItemTRIMA]').hide();                
        }else{
            j$('[id*=docsSectionItemA]').hide();
            j$('[id*=docsSectionItemTRIMA]').show();
        }
    }

    function switchDropdown(selected){

        if (selected.value == 'DocumentType'){
            j$('[id*=docsSectionItemA]').show();
            j$('[id*=docsSectionItemTRIMA]').hide();
        } else {
            j$('[id*=docsSectionItemA]').hide();
            j$('[id*=docsSectionItemTRIMA]').show();
        }
    }       

    function switchFile(selected){
        if (selected.value == 'File'){
            j$('[id*=fileInput]').show();
            j$('[id*=folderInput]').hide();
        } else {
            j$('[id*=fileInput]').hide();
            j$('[id*=folderInput]').show();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Had to split up the action region because I need to rerender some sections, which cannot be done with apex:inputFile in the region.

Comment: Can you post the entire page?  Is it possible you have more than one `<apex:form>`, or this is not in the `<apex:actionRegion>` for some reason?

Comment: What value are you trying to send to your controller? and where is your {get;set;}?

Comment: the same value as shown on the dropdown, the label and value are identical in this case. The get;set; are in the controller.